# Possible problems due to repeated ajax calls?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am planning to have a (Telerik MVC) grid in which each row has a button. On click, a boolean will be updated in the DB via ajax and the callback function will set a "checkmark" image in one of the row's cells. The user should be able to click on multiple rows in rapid-fire fashion, and I'm trying to anticipate any problems if he does so. Is there a possibility of contention either in the DOM or in the database server?

Comment: Try it and see if you have any problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that user experience does not suffer, here's what I'd do:

- Create an array of objects to be update
- Every time an checkbox is clicked, add/update it to/in the array with the value - this will make sure that multiple clicks to the same checkbox will result in only one AJAX call
- After adding a check box to array, start the AJAX update process
- On AJAX response, check if there are any items in the array to be processed and repeat

Answer (score 0):

The biggest factor will probably be how quickly your server handles the Ajax request. If it takes a while, then the user experience will suck.

You could possibly make this better by adding the keys to a variable, and just sending to the server periodically, eg:

1. User clicks an item

   - Add key to array
   - Use window.setTimeout() to kick off the send function in x milliseconds
2. User clicks another item

   - Add key to array
   - Timeout already set, so doesn't do anything more
3. Timeout expires, code runs, sends both keys to server in one request
4. User clicks an item

   - Add key to array
   - Use window.setTimeout() to kick off the send function in x milliseconds

etc.